# Запятая перед сочинительным союзом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, однородные-члены, и

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая перед "и затем передать" в следующем предложении?

*Все три способа не исключают друг друга: вы можете сначала заработать на книге с online-продаж, выпустить и продать лимитированный тираж и затем передать права в издательство.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая не нужна. Первый союз ***и*** стоит между связанными в единое целое глаголами ***выпустить*** и ***продать***, а второй соединяет последний однородный член всей цепочки: *можете **заработать**, **выпустить** и **продать** и **передать***. (Тем более что однородность исходит из первого предложения: *Все три способа*...)

[Однородные члены предложения, соединенные повторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101) (Розенталь)

> 8. Если два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом ***и***, образуют тесно связанную по смыслу пару, соединенную союзом ***и*** с третьим однородным членом, запятая не ставится: <...> *Фыркает конь и ушами прядёт, брызжет и плещет и дале **плывёт***.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!